# How to restart build in jenkins (github pull request) after adding a label

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I have created a pull request, after creating pull request the jenkins job will be started.
this job runs only onece, I do want to restart jenkins job after pushing something new in the branch.

my idea is that the jenkins job will be only restarted, if I add a label such as "rebuild"

[image]

My question is, how can I setup in Jenkins configuartion?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restart the build by adding a label when using the GitHub Pull Request builder plugin.

By default, the plugin is configured to trigger a new build when you add a new comment with the phrase `retest this please` to the pull request (you can change the phrase in the plugin configuration)

Comment: it sounds great, can you give more information? thx

Comment: I have found this solution triggers {
    gitlab(
        ...
        triggerOnNoteRequest: true,
        noteRegex: "restart pipeline",
        ...
    )
}

Comment: but this is for gitlab, I need a solution for github

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) of the plugin, it contains both the plugin configuration and job configuration